# select vs find and where vs find in Mongoose

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

In the Mongoose documentation there is this little snippet:

```
Person
.find({ occupation: /host/ })
.where('name.last').equals('Ghost')
.where('age').gt(17).lt(66)
.where('likes').in(['vaporizing', 'talking'])
.limit(10)
.sort('-occupation')
.select('name occupation')
.exec(callback);
```

I am having a hard time understanding what the `.find({ occupation: /host/ })` does different than the `.select('name occupation')`. Does find add conditions like where? or does it control the fields returned? 
**UPDATE**
Ok, so i see that select only controls the fields from the final result of the queries, but now I do not understand how `Find` and `Where` are different. Am I not able to create the same queries using `Find` and using `Where`? Is the following snippet the same?

```
Person
.where('occupation').equals('host')
.where('name.last').equals('Ghost')
.where('age').gt(17).lt(66)
.where('likes').in(['vaporizing', 'talking'])
.limit(10)
.sort('-occupation')
.select('name occupation')
.exec(callback);
```

Comment: .find sets up the query (and filters results), where as .select dicates what fields of those results are returned. Enable mongoose debug to see the generated mongo queries to better understand what's happening behind the scenes.

Comment: `select` specifies the fields you want to select.  It would be similar to `.find({ occupation: /host/ }, "name occupation")`

Comment: @KevinB ok, so then how is find different from where then?

Comment: .where filters the documents, and .select tells mongo what to return within the document. for example, only getting the id, vs getting the whole document. It can also be used with methods such as $elemMatch to select only the first matching subdocument within each document.

Comment: @KevinB so find fetchs based on conditions, where filters that result set, and select returns only the fields of the filtered result set?

Comment: `where` simply adds to the conditions you passed to `find`. .select adds to the second argument.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`find` is the actual query. In this example you are getting all rows that have `occupation` equal to `host`. Now each of the object that matches that query has several attributes. Lets assume it has the attributes `name`, `age`, `email` and `occupation`. When you specify that you want to `select` `name` and `occupation` you say that you just want those attributes. So in our case `age` and `email` will not be sent back from the query.

`where` in this case is used to specify more than one constraint against which to query. Usually, `where` is used because it provides greater flexibility than `find` such as passing in javascript expressions

Comment: so how is find different from where?

Comment: Edited my asnwer to explain ```where```

Comment: thanks Dan. So, based on your edit, is it safe to say i can build a query without using `find` for defining my query and only use `where`? Also, are you aware of any performance differences between using find and using where?

Comment: I dont know wether there are performance differences but yea you could deffinately do something like Schema.find({}).where(<--query here-->)

Comment: It's less about performance and more about being able to build the query over several different pieces of middleware or different functions. for example, i usually have my `.select()` statements in a separate function that checks what fields the authenticated user is allowed to view, and omits any fields they aren't allowed to view, i can then reuse that same function for findOne, findMany, and Search routes to ensure the user only sees what I want them to see.

Comment: Note from the [docs](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/query/where/) that $where requires that the database processes the JavaScript expression or function for *each* document in the collection.

Answer (score 2):

From the [API docs on `select`](http://mongoosejs.com/docs/api.html#query_Query-select):

> **Query#select(`arg`)**
>
> Specifies which document fields to include or exclude

`.select('name occupation')` says that results should only include the `name` and `occupation` fields. You do not wish to see any other fields in your results.

`find` describes which documents to include in the results. `select` indicates which fields of those documents should be visible in the results.